# How to re-write this code using functional and more efficient style?

Tags: kotlin

**Description:**
We are given a list of integers, for example `[2,2,0,2,0,3,1,1]`. Think of it as a stock of some material that vary over time. The indexation is assumed to start from 1.  At time unit 1 we have two units of that material, at time unit 6 we have 3 units etc.

We are given a container of a fixed size. We are allowed to fill one unit of the material for one time index.

For example, if the size of the container is 3 and we start filling at time index 1:

- At time index 1 we will fill one unit (even if there is 2 units available)
- At time index 2 we will also fill 1 unit
- At time index 3, nothing to fill because there is a zero stock
- At time index 4 we will fill one unit. Thus the container is full

The aim is to answer the question for every possible time index.

PS: we are not allowed to start filling when there is zero available units

**My attempt :**

```kotlin
fun givenStartComputeLength(start: Int, containerSize : Int, table: List<Int>) : Int{
    var howLongItWillTake = -1
    var cumulated = 0
    for (index in start until table.size){
        if (table[index] > 0){
            cumulated += 1
        }
        if (cumulated == containerSize){
            howLongItWillTake = index - start + 1
            break
        }
    }
    return howLongItWillTake
}

fun startsToLengths(containerSize : Int, table: List<Int>) : Map<Int,Int>{
    val startToLength = mutableMapOf<Int,Int>()
    for (index in 1..table.size-containerSize+1){
        if (table[index-1] != 0){
            val length = givenStartComputeLength(index-1, containerSize, table)
            startToLength[index] = length
        }
    }
    return startToLength
}

fun main() {
val table = listOf(2,2,0,2,0,3,1,1)
    //Manual resolution : 
   /// starts 1 ---> ends at 4 --> length 4 (i.e it will take 4 time units)
  /// starts 2 --> ends at 6 --> length 5
  /// starts 4 --> ends at 7 --> length 4
  // starts 6 ---> ends at 8 --> length 3   
println(startsToLengths(3,table)) // output {1=4, 2=5, 4=4, 6=3}

val table2 = listOf(2,2,0,2,0,3,0,1)
println(startsToLengths(3,table2)) //Output{1=4, 2=5, 4=5, 6=-1}
}
```

**Question:** It works but I don't think that I am writing neither a kotlin- style code, nor an efficient code. I think a more functionnal-fashion would be better. Any help?

Comment: I don't have a clear picture of what we're supposed to find. Looks like you end up with a map of indices to something you're calling length, but only indices where the input table contained non-zero values. What is length? Are the values in the input table completely irrelevant as long as you know whether they are zero or not?

Comment: Yup, the values are irrelevant, the only thing that matters is whether it's zero or not. The map is for each start it gives how long it will take (i.e the number of indexes). Does this help?

Comment: How long does it take to totally fill the container. For example i have a table `[2,2,0,2,0,3,1,1]`, and a container of size 3. Letś say I start filling it at time unit 1 (i. e index 0 in the table). I will consume one unit at index 0 (because `table[0] =2 >0`), one unit at unit 2 (index 1), 0 unit at the time unit 3 (because `table[2] = 0`)  and then one unit at time unit 4. Thus I end filling at 4 because I reached the size of my container. I started at 1 and ended at 4 ==> It took me 4 -1 + 1. That's the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main idea to make algorithm that will be O(table.size) because right now it O(table.size ** 2). We can calculate result for next step just using previous step result and this save our efforts.

[image]

There is link to  [Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/2o5lwUgYw):

```
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code. 
 * play.kotlinlang.org 
 */

fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    
    fun startsToLengths(containerSize : Int, table: List<Int>) : Map<Int,Int> {
        
        val startToLength = mutableMapOf<Int,Int>()
        var s = 0
        var e = 0
        val l = table.size-containerSize + 1
        var count = 0 
        var len = 0
        
        while (s < l) {
            
            while (table[s] == 0 && s < l ) { 
                
                s++ 
                
                len--
            }
            
            if (s == l) { break }

            if (e < l ) { e = l }
            
            while (e < table.size) {
                
                if (table[e] > 0) { count++ }
                
                e++
                len++
                
                if (count == containerSize) {
                    
                    startToLength[s+1] = len
                    
                    if (table[s] > 0) { count-- }
                    
                    s++
                    len--
             
                    break
                    
                } else if (e == table.size) {
                    
                    startToLength[s+1] = -1
                    
                    s = l 
                    
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        return startToLength
    }
    val table = listOf(2,2,0,2,0,3,1,1)
    
    println(startsToLengths(3,table)) 
}
```